# How to use shared_examples_for in rsepc-mock？I have try many times but failed.who can help ,please? Wait online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

I am a freshman on Rspec

```
it "should not ask the database" do
  @sqlite_database.should_not_receive(:findISBN)
  @result = @cache.findISBN('1234') 
  @result.should eql(@book) 
end

it "should not ask the database" do
  @sqlite_database.should_not_receive(:authorSearch)
  @result = @cache.authorSearch('author') 
  @result.should eql(@book) 
end
```

Here are two different part 1,:findISBN and :authorSearch 2 findISBN('1234') and authorSearch('author')

I try to  use let but it doesn't work ,who can help ?

@sqlite_database = double()
 @cache = SQLiteDataBaseWithCache.new(@sqlite_database)
 That's ture ,I'm coming from java background .You coding showed some warning: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError).I have no ideal about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without more details on the variables like @sqlite_database, @cache etc its hard to tell whats happening, but following should work

probably a stack trace would help

following is the idea of shared examples :)

```
shared_examples "it should not ask database" do |symbol, params| 
 it "should not ask the database" do
   @sqlite_database.should_not_receive(symbol)
   @result = @cache.send symbol, params 
   @result.should eql(@book) 
 end
end

it_behaves_like "it should not ask the database", :findISBN, '1234'
it_behaves_like "it should not ask the database", :authorSearch, 'author'
```

and on a side note, your method signatures are not ruby kind of... in ruby we normally dont use camel case

so in ruby/rails its should be author_search, probably you are coming from java background :)

Comment: Hi I still can't solve the problem and I have add more information